# Swift local notification icon badge number not incrementing

Tags: uilocalnotification, badge

I have a problem.
my app icon badge is not incrementing when a notification fires. i can only set

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

to 0 or 1.

if i set

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
```

Badge number updates only the first time, and then remain at its value.

There is a method to increment that value?i have searched internet but i can't figure out how solve this problem.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set that badge number with the UIApplication singleton object, instead of assigning a counter to a local notification.

Comment: i tried  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 in the app delegate.swift file but the problem still persists...

Answer (score 0):

Just check out my answer on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55615254/11340995
The secret is to increment