# Swift - Local notification icon badge number update on deliver App is in background

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to figure how I can update dynamically the icon badge number when a local notification is delivered. 
Registering the badge number upon scheduling is not an option since if I register two or more notification before any are delivered the

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber // this will be zero
```

will always be zero until a notification is delivered.

I can use the UNUsernotification delegate with the func

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { }
```

but this function is called just if the app is active. 
What if the app is not active?

I've read a bit around and pretty much everyone i've read says there is no way to do such a thing! But is this even possible??

How the Apple manage the notification for reminder and calendar? are they local notification and they update the icon badge? or am I making a mistake? I believe it must be a way to update the icon badge when the local notification is delivered?

Any idea guys? can't believe Apple did not provide a way to achieve this! Thank you!

Comment: How is this question different from your other question with a really similar title: [UNUserNotification checking changes in badge number icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281910/swift-unusernotification-checking-changes-in-badgenumbericon)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - UNUsernotification checking changes in BadgeNumberIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281910/swift-unusernotification-checking-changes-in-badgenumbericon)

Comment: @DávidPásztor it's a generic question... I'm wondering how such a thing is possible...I just opened a new thread because i'm really curious to understand.. if for real it does not exist such a possibility... so the difference is that i'm trying to get people point of view independently from my issue on the app..

Comment: @DávidPásztor and if you check the question you linked the solution there is for the app not being in background...

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to increase the badge for both repetitive and scheduled notifications, you should increase UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber, before configuring the notification:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
```

And then just simply:

```
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                notificationContent.title = "Test"
                notificationContent.subtitle = "Test"
                notificationContent.body = "Test"
                notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                notificationContent.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber as NSNumber
```

In order to reset the counter every time the user opens the app, just simply set the value of UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0 in AppDelegate.swift like this:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UNMutableNotificationContent has a property call badge. You set this property before trigger de notification and that's it!
Badge number property is NSNumber so it's a little tricky incrementing it by 1.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:
        "Your Last Time Alarm!", arguments: nil)
content.body = self.userInfo["descripcion"]!
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default  
content.badge = NSNumber(value: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)
```

The rest is set the trigger and add the request:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false) 
  let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: idNotificacion, content: content, trigger: trigger) 
  let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
  center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
    if let theError = error {
      print(theError)
    } else {
       ...
    }
  }
```